# Echart graphic not show all data when open page

Tags: javascript, echarts

I would like to show data on graphic chart. I am using Echarts graphics but when open the page all the data shown at beginning. Can you help me to show only 2016 active when open the page and other years deactive, when visitors click that data can appear.

Here is my ECharts option:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('bar-chart'));
option = {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data:['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019']
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
      magicType: { show: true, type: ['line', 'bar'] },
      restore: { show: true },
      saveAsImage: { show: true }
    }
  },
  color: ["#55ce63", "#009efb", "#b20202", "#a8b202"],
  calculable: true,
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      data: [  
       'Jan','Feb','Mar',
       'Apr','May','Jun',
       'Jul','Aug','Sep',
       'Oct','Nov','Dec'
      ]
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type : 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: '2016',
      type: 'line',
      data: [...],
      markPoint: {...},
      markLine: {...}
    },{
      name: '2017',
      type: 'line',
      data: [...],
      markPoint: {...},
      markLine: {...}
    },{
      name: '2018',
      type: 'line',
      data: [...],
      markPoint: {...},
      markLine: {...}
    },{
      name: '2019',
      type: 'line',
      data: [...],
      markPoint: {...},
      markLine: {...}
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer I posted was not a good one since it needed external JS functions to process the `options` object. Here is a quick working solution using ECharts' built-in `legend.selected` property:

```
legend: { 
  data:['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'],
  selected: {
    '2016': true,
    '2017': false,
    '2018': false,
    '2019': false
  }
},
```

As you can imagine, `true` shows the series by default and `false` hides it until the user clicks on the legend icon to make it visible.